# D3 - Grid when the axis is in the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I have the following D3 chart (use 12842311 as input):  http://www.uscfstats.com/deltas

After loading the chart, click the grid button (only after loading).  A grid will appear.  The obvious problem is that the vertical lines are only on the top half of the chart.

This is because D3, as far as I know, only lets you specify an offset for the beginning of the tick mark, which is how I'm doing it, and then doesn't let you specify an ending offset.  I also think that you have to do it with tick marks because otherwise you don't know the location of the ticks unless you do something complicated.

How can I get around this limitation and do a grid with vertical lines across the x-axis?  It seems like it shouldn't be difficult.  Am I even going about the creation of a grid in the right way?

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom").scale(x).ticks(15);

svg.append("g").attr("class","x axis").call(xAxis).attr("transform","translate(60, " + height + ")");
```

Comment: I don't see a grid on your example page, is it no longer working? Can you create a jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: You have to click the "Grid" button.

Comment: I did. Console shows `xAxis is not defined`.

Comment: It should only say that before the chart loads?  Did you submit 12842311 first?

Comment: Ah, entered the number but didn't hit `Go` before `Grid` :) Now I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I could get this to work was to manually resize and translate the `tick` marks.

```
  svg.selectAll(".y line")
      .attr("x2", width);

  svg.selectAll(".x line")
      .attr("y2", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (-y(0)) + ")");
```

You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/2y3er/2/.

Answer (score 0):

You can make two sets of tick SVG elements, one extending in the positive direction and the other in the negative direction.

Modify your d3 setup to include another axis or two, but this time include the modified `tick` parameters in your `call` method:

```
Dim xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(...).ticks(... // define your xAxis generator

Dim xAxisSVG = d3.selectAll(...)... // and your standared axis
        .call(xAxis);

Dim xPositiveTicks = d3.selectAll(...)... // positive grid lines
        .call(xAxis.tickSize(height));

Dim xNegativeTicks = d3.selecatAll(...)... // negative grid lines
        .call(xAxis.tickSize(-1 * height));
```

I know that's not terribly thorough, but that method has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: This did not work for me, unfortunately.  I used this code, and a similar piece for the xNegativeTicks.  Also see the end of the edited question.  
var xPositiveTicks = d3.selectAll(".x.axis").call(xAxis.tickSize(height));